# Pre-provision MySite user site via script?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint

We're considering pre-provisioning each user's MySite in SP 2010 - I know MS don't recommend it but it's a Uni installation and we'd like to have the student accounts set up in advance rather than have everything go bananas when a few thousand people all turn up on the same day and start having a look around our available services.

Can this be done via a script of some sort?  I presume Powershell has some mechanism to trigger the creation without the user having to physically visit their site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started - you'll need to wrap the site creation part in a loop over your user list and possibly add some more error checking.

I know for sure this works in 2007 but haven't tested it in 2010. All the same stuff exists so it should. One final thing - this is SLOW - creating 1 user on my SP2007 server takes 5-10 seconds. If your mysites farm is beefy enough, you might actually be better off letting the users create their personal sites ad-hoc.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")

$siteurl = "http://your.mysitesurl.com"    

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site)
$upm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

# start loop here
$user = "domain\username"
if ($upm.UserExists($user)) {
    $profile = $upm.GetUserProfile($user)

    # there are other exceptions you can catch, check out the UserProfiles class
    trap [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteExistsException] {
            Write-Host "personal site already exists for $user"
            continue
    }
    $profile.CreatePersonalSite();
}  else {
  Write-Host: "user $user did not exist"
}
# end loop here

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks this is great.  I expect the creation to be slow but we have the benefit of a window in the summer when we can set up any new students before they arrive by running this over a few nights if we need to.  You've been a big help on this and most of my SharePoint questions!

Comment: @Chris, Did this work?

Comment: Didn't end up using it - the rollout ended up being phased enough that we didn't need to worry about too many people all hitting it at once.